# jQuery: Confirmation dialog before leaving a page while in editing mode

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to appear a message when the user edit some field and try to go to another page or click close to the page

message appear

**This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved.**

I use this code :

```
$('#form').data('serialize',$('#form').serialize());
  // On load save form current state

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e){
    if($('#form').serialize()!=$('#form').data('serialize'))return true;
    else e=null;
    // i.e; if form state change show box not.
});
```

This code works only when the user try to edit something if not I can close the page and thats what I want.

The problem is that the message appear also when I submit the form

When I try to `click` the `button` submit the message appear also

**This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved.**

How to prevent to show that message when I click the submit button ??!!

Comment: Keep a **flag** as `alse`, whenever you start editing in the page set the **flag** value to `true`. Then in `beforeunload` check for the **flag** value & set the message accordingly. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?  Keeping a flag defeats the purpose of using comparing the serailzed form values.

Answer (score 0):

Save the listener in a variable and remove it on submit

```js
const onBeforeUnloadListener function(e){
    if($('#form').serialize()!=$('#form').data('serialize'))return true;
    else e=null;
    // i.e; if form state change show box not.
}

$(window).bind('beforeunload', onBeforeUnloadListener);

$('#form').on('submit', function() {
   $(window).unbind('beforeunload', onBeforeUnloadListener)
}
```

Comment: your code doesn't work when i use your code i can close the page and go to another page when i edit something in my form